# Limit of cashable files in firefox with service worker?

Tags: javascript, firefox, service-worker

I hope someone can help me with this.

During the installing phase of my service worker I try to cache 100 files but Firefox only caches 50 or 60 of them, different ones every time I install the service worker.

While monitoring the caching I get no errors but after installation is done half of the files are just not in the cache. This is with Firefox 75 on both MacOS Catalina and Windows 10. It all works fine in Safari, Edge, Chrome.

The testfiles I'm caching are 3kb each and using 'storage' and 'estimate' I see that there's plenty of free space available.

Here's my service worker code. I tried it both with the cache.addAll and forEach to monitor the caching but the result is the same: around half of the files are missing.

```
    const CACHE_NAME = 'limit-test-cache-v1';
    const urlsToCache = [
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata1.pdf',
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata2.pdf',
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata3.pdf',
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata4.pdf',
    ...
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata97.pdf',
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata98.pdf',
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata99.pdf',
        '/serviceworker-limit/testdata/testdata100.pdf'
    ];
    const cacheSize = urlsToCache.length;
    let counter = 0;

    self.addEventListener('install', event => {
        event.waitUntil(

            /*
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
                cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
            */


            caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
                console.log('Opened cache');
                urlsToCache.forEach(url => {
                    const req = new Request(url);
                    cache.add(req).then(() => {
                        counter++;
                        console.log(url + ' has been cached. Message ' + counter + ' of total: ' + cacheSize);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        counter++;
                        console.log('Error while caching' + url + '. Error ' + err);
                    });
                });
            })


        );
    });
```

Since there are no errors I basically do not know what to search for. Is this expected behaviour somehow? Is my code wrong? Is this a Firefox bug? Are the flat-earthers right after all? If anyone can give me some pointers it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, or experiences an identical issue, this problem was caused by a combination of two issues:

1. I checked the cache size immediately after the service workers state changed from 'activiating' to 'activated'. As stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) (see first note) this can be too soon as the content body of a fetched files might still be streaming and the cache will not be ready yet. I would expect the cache size would count database entries but apparently this is not the case.
2. The cache storage view in Firefox' dev tools only shows a limited number of cached files. A note like: 'only the first 60 cached files are displayed here' would help prevent misunderstanding the situation but ultimately there should be some sort of pagination here. Maybe the issue is solved in the Application panel of the devEdition of Firefox.